# How to programatically download files with increased speed in android

Tags: android, download

Hi have implemented programatically downloading of file using inputstream and cipheroutputstream(for encryption). The download is happening very slow. Whereas if i try to download via download manager, it is very fast. What can i do to improve my code and increase the download speed of the file. Below is my code.

```
 private void saveFileUsingEncryption(String aMineType, long length) throws Exception {

    int bufferSize = 1024*4;

    //byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    long totalRead = 0;

    FileOutputStream outStream = null;

    File f = new File(Constants.DWLPATH);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }

    try {

        Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("ARC4");
        aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,  new SecretKeySpec("mykey".getBytes(), "ARC4"));

        if(contDisp==null || contDisp.length()==0) {
            // downloadFileName = downloadFileName.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", "");
            downloadFileName = downloadFileName + "." + getFileExtension(aMineType);

        }

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(Constants.DWLPATH +  downloadFileName,true);
        CipherOutputStream out = new CipherOutputStream(outStream, aes);

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) >= 0) {

            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            try{
                // Adjust this value. It shouldn't be too small.
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
              TraceUtils.logException(e);
            }
            totalRead += bytesRead;
            sb=sb.append("\n Total bytes Read:"+totalRead);
            Log.e("--",sb.toString());
           /* if (this.length > 0) {
                Long[] progress = new Long[5];
                progress[0] = (long) ((double) totalRead / (double) this.length * 100.0);


                publishProgress(progress);
            }*/

            if (this.isCancelled()) {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.disconnect();
                conn = null;
                break;
            }

        }
        Log.e("Download completed","success");
        out.flush();
        //Utils.putDownloadLogs(requestUrl,mimeType,length, downloadFileName,"Download is Successful",sb.toString(), context);
        outStream.close();


        buffer = null;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        TraceUtils.logException( e);

        file_newsize = storedFileSizeInDB + totalRead;
        if (totalFileSize == 0)
            totalFileSize = length;

        callback.onRequestInterrupted(file_newsize,totalFileSize);

        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        // Utils.putDownloadLogs(requestUrl,mimeType,length,downloadFileName,"failure---" + errors.toString(),sb.toString(), context);


        throw e;

    } finally {
        if (outStream != null)
            outStream.close();
        outStream = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default download manager to download the file because its very easy to implement and provide better features like respond to the internet connection , provide accessibility to add notification in status bar , by running the query on download manager object you can find the total bytes and remaining bytes so you can calculate the progress and after completion of download by tapping the notification one can perform the desired operation.

And also there are many libraries are available for to achieve this like

[PRDOWNLOADER](https://medium.com/mindorks/prdownloader-a-file-downloader-library-for-android-b9c5fc56a640)
[FetchDownloader](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch)

This libraires provide you the feature of pause,download, resume download , tracking the progress and cancel download

Also you can customize it as per your need.

Comment: My requirement is to download programatically and not via download manager.

Comment: If u can provide any improvement to the code i posted, it will be of help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `DownloadAndEncryptFileTask.class` to download with encryption

```
public class DownloadAndEncryptFileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private String mUrl;
private File mFile;
private Cipher mCipher;

InputStream inputStream;
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream;

public DownloadAndEncryptFileTask(String url, File file, Cipher cipher) {
    if (url == null || url.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You need to supply a url to a clear MP4 file to download and encrypt, or modify the code to use a local encrypted mp4");
    }
    mUrl = url;
    mFile = file;
    mCipher = cipher;
}

private void downloadAndEncrypt() throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL(mUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    if (mFile.length() > 0) {
        connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + mFile.length() + "-");
    }
    connection.connect();

    Log.e("length", mFile.length() + "");


    if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        throw new IOException("server error: " + connection.getResponseCode() + ", " + connection.getResponseMessage());
    }


    inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    if (mFile.length() > 0) {
        //connection.connect();
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile, true);

    } else {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
    }

    CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(fileOutputStream, mCipher);

    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "reading from http...");

        cipherOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    cipherOutputStream.close();
    connection.disconnect();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        downloadAndEncrypt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "done");
}
}
```

Call this class

```
new DownloadAndEncryptFileTask(
    myFeedsModel.getVideo().getVideo360(),
    new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), myFeedsModel.getFile_name()),
    OBJECT OF YOUR CIPHER
```

Comment: I am aware of all this and have used. My only requirement is how i can increase the download speed.